# functions.database.ref().onWrite() isn't called when value changes on database emulator

Tags: database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I'm trying to set up an open source app on my computer for personal use, if anyone wants to have a look at the full code: https://github.com/kimar/jukebox-app. (functions/lib/vote-processor.ts)
I'm not experienced in any way regarding this topic and would be really happy if someone can help.

For testing I changed the firebase part to use the firebase emulator, everything seems to work fine except the following:

```
export const processVotes = functions.database.ref('/votes/{partyId}/{trackId}/{userId}')
```

Even though the function is initialized (console output: functions[us-central1-processVotes]: database function initialized.) it's never called. Both database and functions emulator are running.

I checked the path and it should be right but no matter what is changed the function won't trigger (what I expect it to do).

Comment: If possible can you also share the structure of your realtime db with masking the database url.